# How to correctly integrate R and python in a single jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, rpy2

I'm currently modelling a dataset and I wanted to use both R and Python in its task. I tried to install rpy2 by pip, but after its instalation when I try to load the extention in a python 3 notebook in Jupyter I have the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 184: invalid continuation byte
```

I think it mighty be an error doing the instalation although the prompt indicated the success in instalation. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Your title is not very specific to your actual issue, see [the section 'Write a title that summarizes the specific problem'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Plus you aren't indicating how "when I try to load the extention in a python 3 notebook in Jupyter I have the following error". To maybe try and troubleshoot it may be helpful to have a place where R and Python will work together, click [here](http://mybinder.org/v2/gh/binder-examples/r-conda/master?urlpath=%2Ftree%2F) to launch such a session served via the mybinder.org. service. Once the session starts up in the classic  ...

Comment: <continued> Jupyter notebook interface, you need to do some further preparation to use rpy2 with the `%%R` magic in a cell. Open a new notebook with the Python kernel backing it using `New` drop down on the upper right side and then choose the Python3 kernel. When it opens, make a cell that has `%pip install numpy` on the first line and then `%pip install rpy2` on the next next line. Then restart the kernel after that runs and in a new cell put `%load_ext rpy2.ipython` and it should work. (Ignore a warning about Pandas , or install it as well.).Now in the next cell put `%%R` on the first ...

Comment: <continued> line and put some R code on the next cell. It should now run R inside the notebook that is otherwise based on the Python 3 kernel. Try with something simple like `2 + 2`. Hopefully comparing some of this to your situation to try and get a better idea where/how things are failing. (Setting it up was based on the top of [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/interfacing-r-from-python-3-jupyter-notebook-jared-stufft) with a little trouble-shooting of the set-up in that particular environment.)